# Xquery - Finding minimum attribute per group.

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have an XML document that looks like:

```
<charities>
    <charity char_id="x211x">
        <donor type="other" amount="300" />
        <donor type="corporation" amount="250" />
        <donor type="individual" amount="50" />
    </charity>
    <charity char_id="x202x">
        <donor type"other" amount="25" />
        <donor type="individual" amount="25" />
        <donor type="corporation" amount="500" />
    </charity>
</charities>
```

I want to be able to use xquery to return the minimum donation for each charity, with that charity's ID and the amount that was donated. Where there are ties for minimum, both are reported

So the result would, in this case, look like:

```
<minDonors>
    <charity char_id="x211x">
        <donation amount="50">individual</donation>
    </charity>
    <charity char_id="x202x">
        <donation amount="25">other</donation>
        <donation amount="25">individual</donation>
     </charity>
</minDonors>
```

So far I could only get by with a mess of using the min function but I just end up comparing the value to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `min(...)`:

```
<minDonors>{
  for $charity in //charity
  let $min-donation := min($charity/donor/@amount/number())
  return <charity>{
    $charity/@char_id,
    for $donor in $charity/donor[@amount = $min-donation]
    return <donation amount="{$donor/@amount}">{
      $donor/@type/string()
    }</donation>
  }</charity>
}</minDonors>
```

Using XQuery 3 `count` together with `order by` (most probably less efficient):

```
<minDonors>{
  for $charity in //charity
  return <charity>{
    $charity/@char_id,
    for $donor in $charity/donor
    group by $amount := $donor/@amount
    order by xs:double($amount)
    count $c
    where $c = 1
    for $donation in $donor
    return <donation amount="{$amount}">{
      $donation/@type/string()
    }</donation>
  }</charity>
}</minDonors>
```